# How can i use circular Progress indicator in my cocoa programming?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

this is my code and i want use this object to show loading progress,what should i do?

// view.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import<WebKit/WebKit.h>

 @interface view : NSObject {
  IBOutlet WebView* webview;
  }
 -(IBAction) google:(id) sender;

 @end
```

//view.m

```
 #import "view.h"

@implementation view
  -(IBAction) google:(id) sender
  {
   [[webview mainFrame] loadRequest:
   [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
   [NSURL   URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/finance/converter"]]];
   }

  @end
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at [WebResourceLoadDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebResourceLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003836). Also, from [WebView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference page:

> Another way to monitor load progress with less control is to observe the WebViewProgressEstimateChangedNotification, WebViewProgressFinishedNotification, and WebViewProgressStartedNotification notifications. For example, you could observe these notifications to implement a simple progress indicator in your application. You update the progress indicator by invoking the estimatedProgress method to get an estimate of the amount of content that is currently loaded.

Comment: my programming is cocoa not cocoa touch .i think UIWebViewDelegate dosen't exist.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Updated the answer accordingly